# is there a tool for windows 7 that can find which program is modifying a particular file

Tags: windows, security, monitoring, files

My system is infected by a malware that keeps modifying a particular configuration file. Is there a way/tool to find out which program is making change to a particular file?

I am simply looking for a tool that can help monitor changes to a particular file. Not really a full fledged forensics response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) out of the [Microsoft Sysinternals suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb842062.aspx) should do the trick.
You can filter the path or registry key or whatever you need.